# Resetar Form depois do Envio

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Bom dia, tenho um formulario de envio, mas os dados ficam nos inputs assim q clico pra enviar... como resetar os forms?

Segue o codigo

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
   define('SERVIDOR', 'contato@meusite.com.br');
   define('DESTINO', 'contato@meusite.com.br');
   define('SITE', 'Meu Site');

   if (isset($_POST)):
       $nome    = (isset($_POST['contatoNome']))? $_POST['contatoNome']: '';
       $email   = (isset($_POST['contatoEmail']))? $_POST['contatoEmail']: '';
       $msg     = (isset($_POST['contatoMensagem']))? $_POST['contatoMensagem']: '';

// Valida se foram preenchidos todos os campos
if (empty($nome) || empty($email) || empty($msg)):
    $array  = array('tipo' => 'alert alert-danger', 'mensagem' => 'Preencher todo os campos obrigatórios(*)!');
    echo json_encode($array);
else:

    if (empty($assunto)):
        $assunto = "Contato enviado pelo site " . SITE;
    endif;

    // Monta a mensagem do email
    $mensagem = "Contato enviado pelo site ".SITE."\n";
    $mensagem .= "**********************************************************\n";
    $mensagem .= "Nome do Contato: ".$nome."\n";
    $mensagem .= "E-mail do Contato: ".$email."\n";
    $mensagem .= "**********************************************************\n";
    $mensagem .= "Mensagem: \n".$msg."\n";

    // Envia o e-mail e captura o retorno
    $retorno = EnviaEmail(DESTINO, $assunto, $mensagem);

    // Conforme o retorno da função exibe a mensagem para o usuário
    if ($retorno):
        $array  = array('tipo' => 'alert alert-success', 'msgContato' => 'Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!');
        echo json_encode($array);
    else:
        $array  = array('tipo' => 'alert alert-danger', 'msgContato' => 'Infelizmente houve um erro ao enviar sua mensagem!');
        echo json_encode($array);
    endif;

endif;
endif;

// Função para envio de e-mail usando a função nativa do PHP mail()
function EnviaEmail($para, $assunto, $mensagem){

$headers = "From: ".SERVIDOR."\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $para\n";
$headers .= "Subject: $assunto\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: ".SERVIDOR."\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";

$retorno = mail($para, $assunto, nl2br($mensagem), $headers);
return $retorno;
}
```

**Formulário**

```
<form method="post" action="" id="formContato">
  <div id="msgContato" class=""></div>
    <div class="row 50%">
      <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
       <input type="text" name="contatoNome" id="contatoNome" placeholder="Nome" required />
      </div>
      <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
        <input type="text" name="contatoEmail" id="contatoEmail" placeholder="Email" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="12u">
        <textarea name="contatoMensagem" id="contatoMensagem" placeholder="Mensagem" rows="4" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="12u">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><input type="submit" name="contatoEnvia" class="style1" value="Enviar" /></li>                                                      
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Fiz teste e funciona bem, o email foi enviado para minha caixa de correio ( veja em https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl1q0.png). Apos envio veja como a página ficou https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WCwR.png Os dados não ficam nos inputs, eles ficam vazios. Só achei estranho esse  `$array  = array('tipo' => .......`

Answer (score 0):

Tu pode usar a função `reset` do *JavaScript*:

```js
function submitForm() {
   var form = document.getElementById('form');

   form.reset();
   
   return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
</form>
```

Comment: Vou fazer o teste e já te dou o feedback

Comment: O código do formulário como é?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo atualizei a pergunta e coloquei o formulario

Comment: @BetinhoSilva funcionou o reset()?

Comment: @DiegoVieira ele reseta mas nao envia os dados...

Comment: Tu ta enviando esse formulário com ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, se você tiver Hiddens só o reset do javascript não vai adiantar, você terá que criar uma função no backend pra limpar todas os Hiddens com isso você aproveita e já limpa os campos, sem a necessidade de chamar o reset.

Comment: Como eu faria isso? O modelo citado acima nao funcionou....